# Find the sum in 2d array with pointers in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, 2d

I have tried it but i get "sum=6" and it is wrong.
Whats is wrong with the code?
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ROW 2
#define COL 3

int sum(int(*array)[3]);

int main(void)
{
    int a[ROW][COL] = { {1 , 2, 3} ,
                        {4 , 5, 6} };
    printf(" sum = %d\n", sum (a));
    return 0;
}

int sum(int(*array)[3]) 
{
    int i,j, sum = 0;
    for (i =0; i < ROW ; i ++) {
        for (j =0; j < COL ; j ++) {
            sum = sum + *(*( array +i )+j);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Indent your code. 2) You don't actually `return` `sum` anywhere in your `sum` function; you just calculate it.

Comment: Don't use _magic numbers_! You already have macros with the array dimensions, so why not use them in the function declarator, too? Or pass as a VLA with the dimensions.

Comment: And you need to call the function with `sum (&a[0])` to match the declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to return the value of `sum` in your function

```
int sum(int(*array)[3]) 
{
    int i,j, sum = 0;
    for (i =0; i < ROW ; i ++) {
        for (j =0; j < COL ; j ++) {
            sum = sum + *(*( array +i )+j);
        }
    }
    return sum; /* HERE */
}
```

And notice that

```
sum = sum + array[i][j];
```

is more readable than

```
sum = sum + *(*( array +i )+j);
```

Comment: It now shoes "sum=1"

Comment: Yes i know but the exercise ask to find the sum of the array using pointers